# how to download file in ionic and cordova with file transfer ( read only file system Error )

Tags: cordova, ionic-framework

i'm new in cordova and ionic

i want to download audio file from server

my ionic version is : 1.7.14

my cordova version is : 6.1.1

my android version is : 6 ( I use encrypt mode )

here is my code :

```
$scope.DownloadFile = function (url, filename) {

 var ft = new FileTransfer();
   var source = encodeURI('http://' + url + filename);
   var targetPath = cordova.file.documentsDirectory + filename;//change path as you need
   var trustHosts = true;//optional
   var options = {};//optional
   ionic.Platform.ready(function () {//device prepared
     ft.download(source, targetPath, function (entry) {
       alert('success' + JSON.stringify(entry));
     }, function (err) {
       alert(url + filename);
       alert(JSON.stringify(err));
     }, trustHosts, options);
   });
}
```

I get this result :

```
{"code":1 , "source":"http://sedaban.com/sedaban/users/json/app/mobile/download/146012022293952.mp3","target":"null146012022293952.mp3","http_status":200,"body":null,"exception":"/null146012022293952.mp3:open failed: EROFS (Read-only file system)"}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

cordova.file.documentsDirectory is not valid for Android.

This is the description mentioned in cordova file plugin github - "cordova.file.documentsDirectory - Files private to the app, but that are meaningful to other application (e.g. Office files). Note that for OSX this is the user's ~/Documents directory. (iOS, OSX)"

Try out cordova.file.externalDataDirectory or cordova.file.externalRootDirectory for Android. Hope it helps

Comment: I use this cordova.file.externalRootDirectory now I get this ( EACCES (Permission denied) ... and cordova.file.externalDataDirectory give me nothing

Comment: @amirbaqdadi since you are using android marshmalliow, you gotta use the latest version of cordova file plugin  (4.2.0) as the older version has permission issues in folder access with android marshamallow. Hope it helps